# How to notate alternate/secondary melody in ABC

Tags: notation, sheet-music, abc-notation

I'm not able to find any indication that you can do this in ABC, and I was able to use a couple of [Ideographic Space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) characters in the lyrics to make it kinda work and get the lyrics to align, but thought I'd ask anyway. Is there a way to notate the alternate notes for the melody of the second verse?

This is the sheet music I'm trying to replicate:

[image: alternate melody for second verse]

Answer (score 2):

You can come fairly close:

```
X:0
T:lyrics alignment
K:none
M:none
%%score (V1 V2)
[V:V1] A2 A4 y/8 GF
[V:V2] A2 y/8 A2- AAGF
w: joke kid, __ it's a
w: pay kid, _ for what you
```

The required code segment is

```
%%score (V1 V2)
[V:V1] A2 A4 y/8 GF
[V:V2] A2 y/8 A2- AAGF
w: joke kid, __ it's a
w: joke kid, _ for what you
```

I tried using grace-notes to finesse the small-font notes, but they don't allow for a quarter-note, can't control the stem direction, and can't align lyrics to them.

Answer (score 0):

This works on http://www.mandolintab.net/abcconverter.php but not in FiveLineSkink 2.0 Beta, so it might depend on the software you use:

```
    [| A2 A4- GF &\
     A2 A2 AAGF|]
```

The `&\` is what allows us to express multiple voices.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you seek I believe is here, in section 4.6.3

http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1:proposals:clefs_voice_parameters:v2

Just in case it helps anyone else:

This is called a different 'voice'. The origin of this is harmony (chords) originate in people singing together. Chord literally means in accord - with one another in French. Usually the top voice is 1 and any addtional voices are 2, 3 or etc. By ABC notation do you mean tradition sheet music?

Comment: ABC is a notation system. You can read more here: http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1. For a summary, have a look at the [Meta page.documentation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/documentation-for-abcjs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I knew nothing about this. Reminds me of Lilypond